# Aws private hosted zone dns not getting resolved from different vpcs in same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-networking

I created a private hosted zone abc.com and associate it with 2 VPCs, vpc-1 and vpc-2. There is a resource in private subnet in vpc-1 running a http service and for this there is a record added in private hosted zone, svc.abc.com. Now svc.abc.com is successfully getting accessed (200 http response code is returned) from other resources in vpc-1, but resources in vpc-2 are not able to resolve svc.abc.com. Both VPCs are associated with aws default DHCP option set as well.

Considering all the resources private hosted zone and VPCs are in same aws account I am expecting vpc-2 to be able to successfully resolve svc.abc.com. Can anyone suggest what is missing here ?

Comment: Did you check the security group on the resources? May be that is creating problem.

Comment: No that is not the problem as I mentioned other resources in same vpc are able to reach svc.abc.com and moreover SG is allowing all inbound and outbound traffic.

Comment: Is **Enable DNS resolution** for the VPC2 is checked?

Comment: yes it is enabled

Comment: How do you know they aren't able to resolve the DNS? By contrast, how do you know they aren't resolving the DNS, but having trouble connecting after they resolve the IP? What is the specific error message you are getting?

Comment: I did nslookup and looks like it was able to resolve svc.abc.com but since service was running in a private subnet that's why it was unreachable. I added a public service behind svc.abc.com and that was accessible and returning data. Not sure if this is the limitation with private subnet.

Comment: You need to enabled VPC peering between the two VPC. It's not enough that the private hosted zone are associated with the VPCs. You will be able to resolve the DNS but those record will have the private IP from each VPC and you have no routes between them unless you enable VPC peering.

Comment: Agree with @TsalTroser! I am sure you can't ping an IP of one VPC (in same account) from the other VPC. If you are not able to reach to the IP, then how would you access the service. VPC peering seems the missing key.

Comment: @TsalTroser - Adding vpc peering resolved the issue, feel free to add your comment as answer so that I can mark it resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable [VPC peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html) between the two VPCs. It's not enough that the private hosted zone are associated with the VPCs. You will be able to resolve the DNS but that record will have the private IP from each VPC and you have no route between them unless you enable VPC peering and [routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-routing.html).